# collada files and axis center

Tags: collada

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to import a wheel collada file made in SketchUp but when I try to atach it to a joint the axis center is in one fo the edges of the wheel.
How can I set axis in the center of the wheel so It can rotate.
I've already done this with a cylinder instead of a wheel.

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11874/collada-files-and-axis-center/) by [fmarques](https://answers.ros.org/users/1293/fmarques/) on ROS Answers with karma: 92 on 2011-11-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

- This is just a workaround to the axes problem. Still I haven't figured out how to set the axes of the model correctly in the first place. (anyway draw the model in SketchUp assuming its axes coincide with your model axes)
- After exporting it to collada format (.dae) you can use MeshLab to view the axes of your  model: "Render->Show Axis"
- If the axes are not where you want them to be, by looking at MeshLab, change the axes of your model in Google SketchUp: changing it, is easy, because just only one axis is usually misaligned.

---

Originally posted by [ChickenSoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/791/chickensoup/) with karma: 387 on 2012-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0